# How to minimize algae in this case?

Tags: fish, aquarium

I have a 200 liters (100 cm) aquarium. When I bought it I didn't know it could not be placed in front of the window so it grows algae now.

The algae is green and rough. I cannot remove easily. I can only remove with my nails.

The tank doesn't have a background picture(wallpaper).

I'm wondering if putting a background picture and/or a curtain can help deal with that.

It will be painful take off the water and fish in order to move the aquarium to a new place.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup and could lower the algae level temporarily, but never constantly (was as bad as http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12152/how-to-remove-green-bacteria-algae-from-aquarium). In my case adding an undergravel filter solved the issue (a 100x larger filter just removes everything from the water, see http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15506/how-to-get-cristal-clear-water-in-an-aquarium for details). Of course that almost is as much work as moving the tank. I succeeded to install the undergravel filter while the aquarium was running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a opaque background will help if the tank has his back at the window. If it is not the case it won't help with the algae. **As long as your tank sit in direct sun light you will have excessive algae**. There are a few solutions that might help a little bit but the only good one is to move the tank where it is not in direct sunlight.

Here are some ideas

- Have an opaque background around the back and the side of the tank
- Add real plants, they eat the same nutriment as algae, but generally algae are more effective to get those nutrient
- Add livestock that feed on algae (snail, shrimp, some fish, etc.)
- Deal with it by scrapping it regularly and knowing it will need to be redone in a couple of days

Comment: Yes, it has the back at the window. I printed my own background with bond sheet ( I printed the pages and joined them). Is it considered opaque? I will also get a curtain as long I get some extra money.

Comment: If you put it directly on the window, do you see through it? It sure is better than nothing, Any cardboard should do (at least temporarily) so you could use a cereal box or any other cardboard box really

Answer (score 2):

You can add a curtain or a background as you said but you would need to keep it closed for the most part, worth trying if you don't want to relocate it.

When I was working at our local pet store we would use [razor blades](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images2000x2000/X_Acto_X670_X670_Single_Edge_362348.jpg) to scrape the windows (just don't cut yourself), came off really easy. I never found any of the pet store algae scrappers useful for the really hard algae you speak of.

Some people will purchase algae eaters such as [apple snails](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Pomacea.jpg) or [plecostomus](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Plecostomus_1.jpg), I find they do help some but they wouldn't be able to keep up with your problem and they also grow really big.

Comment: Use a rubber scratcher near the silicon joints since even slightly touching it with the razor might harm them - if not the first time, then some of the many time you'll have to use it.